# Get all face colors without plotting the chart on Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot the following values using a moving average approach but I am having some issues getting the right facecolor.

```
difference = [-9.11476554e-03,  6.96440932e-01,  1.55848671e+00,  2.49302039e+00,
        1.78664413e+00,  9.21715740e-01, -9.06779211e-02,  3.85599550e-01,
        7.62364171e-01,  8.43788498e-01,  3.65637016e-01, -3.09278853e-02,
       -3.94263747e-02, -3.99640149e-01, -3.77036512e-01, -9.38614302e-01,
       -9.44227778e-01, -7.56399423e-01, -1.91719761e-01,  1.74602851e-01,
       -1.75804630e-01, -7.88096542e-01, -8.65569748e-01, -9.52364646e-01,
       -3.29532285e-01, -2.49750018e-01, -2.03776029e-03,  3.40896487e-01,
       -1.04289662e-01, -1.11517509e-01,  5.84315453e-02,  1.21235574e+00,
        1.35715932e+00,  1.42280158e+00,  1.24305359e+00,  1.10727093e+00,
        5.28615206e-01, -2.11163359e-02, -4.20183478e-01, -4.22867124e-01,
        9.57720715e-02,  4.81484548e-01,  1.26236096e+00,  1.38971651e+00,
        1.40270113e+00,  6.00938954e-01, -2.46022101e-02, -2.70847276e-02,
       -3.32089611e-03, -1.54348517e-01]
```

First I make a scatter plot using these values and then `length`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 8))
plt.style.use("ggplot")

cmap_name = 'inferno'
scat = ax.scatter(range(len(difference)), difference, c=difference, cmap=cmap_name)
```

[image]

Then, I want the facecolors to draw a lines chart with the moving average:

```
colors = scat.get_facecolors()
ax.plot([0, len(difference)], [0,0], color='dodgerblue', zorder=1, linestyle="-.")
for num, (x0, x1, col) in enumerate(zip(difference[:-1], difference[1:], colors)):
        ax.plot([num, num+1], [x0, x1], color=col, zorder=2)
scat.set_alpha(0)
```

I am using Jupyter Notebooks and if I run these 2 pieces of code in two individual cells it works decently and I get my output.

[image]

However If I combine in one cell, colors have only one element.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 8))
plt.style.use("ggplot")

cmap_name = 'inferno'
scat = ax.scatter(range(len(difference)), difference, c=difference, cmap=cmap_name)

colors = scat.get_facecolors()

ax.plot([0, len(difference)], [0,0], color='dodgerblue', zorder=1, linestyle="-.")
for num, (x0, x1, col) in enumerate(zip(difference[:-1], difference[1:], colors)):
        ax.plot([num, num+1], [x0, x1], color=col, zorder=2)
scat.set_alpha(0)
```

And **colors**:

```
[[0.20392157, 0.54117647, 0.74117647, 1.        ]]
```

and the chart looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get all the `facecolors` without plotting everything and get it afterwards?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the scatter plot has only the first value obtained, so only the first line is drawn. To match the color of the scatter plot, we will convert it to RGBA, set it as the line color, and draw the graph. Also, I don't think the alpha is necessary since it specifies the transparency. The intended graph is to match the colors of the scatterplot and the line graph, and I modified the code to understand that the intent is to create a graph that overlaps them.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 8))
plt.style.use("ggplot")

cmap_name = 'inferno'
scat = ax.scatter(range(len(difference)), difference, c=difference, cmap=cmap_name)

# colors = scat.get_facecolors()
ax.plot([0, len(difference)], [0,0], color='dodgerblue', zorder=1, linestyle="-.")
for num, (x0, x1) in enumerate(zip(difference[:-1], difference[1:])):# , colors[0]
    ax.plot([num, num+1], [x0, x1], color=scat.to_rgba(difference[num]), zorder=2)
# scat.set_alpha(0)

plt.show()
```

[image]